# Add custom tool bar to CKEditor in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor with the CKEditor gem (https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) and everything is working correctly, until I try to add a custom tool bar.

Some posts I've seen suggest using a config.js file. However, with the setup per the instructions, there is no `/ckeditor/config.js` file in `app/assets/javascripts`. Additionally, if I add `/ckeditor/config.js` to the javascripts directory, the file upload functionality stops working. This happens even if `config.js` is an empty file. The "Upload" tab becomes hidden and non-functional with a reboot of the server.

Is there a way I can universally customize the tool bar? Or even if I can just pair down the options inline or something that would be helpful...

Using Rails 3.2.11

**In my Gemfile I have:**

```
gem "jquery-rails", "~> 2.2.1"
gem "ckeditor"
gem "carrierwave"
gem "mini_magick"
gem "cloudinary"
```

**In application.rb I have:**

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)
```

**In application.js I have:**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/.
//= require_tree .
```

**In my form I have:**

```
= f.cktext_area :content
```

**config.js file I attempted to use:**

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
  config.toolbar_Custom = [
    { name: 'document',    items : [ 'Source','-','Save','NewPage','DocProps','Preview','-','Templates' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard',   items : [ 'PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
    { name: 'insert',      items : [ 'Image','Table','HorizontalRule','SpecialChar','PageBreak' ] },
    { name: 'tools',       items : [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks','-','About' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph',   items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl' ] },
    { name: 'links',       items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles',      items : [ 'Styles','Format','Font','FontSize' ] },
    { name: 'colors',      items : [ 'TextColor','BGColor' ] }
  ];

  config.toolbar = 'Custom';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your own config.js file manually. To preserve the Upload tab, follow this issue on the ckeditor gem repo, which explains how to solve it:

https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/238

Just paste the referenced config javascript for the filebrowser into your config.js file and the Upload tab will return with full functionality.